# laravel 7 error 403 forbiden online website

Tags: php, laravel, ionos

I try to put online my project in laravel 7 in ionos, i try to added in public/.htaccess but not worked. After i try to add rights with chmod 777 -R myproject.  it's not worked after i added i have error 404

someone have idea what i can do?

.htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

But after i added in htaccess i have error 404 i dont know what i can do. This project it's doing in laravel 7 . but if i remove rewrite cond i have error 403 forbiden rights issue. Someone have idea how i can put online my website without problems?

Comment: Check your log file about the error and post here

Comment: This file logging.php ?

Comment: `.../storage/logs/`

Comment: i have 2 files .laravel.log and .gitignore

Comment: Its laravel.logs

Comment: Delete all data fresh m laravel.logs then try to access the url again. Then paste the error code in your question

Comment: Dont work it's rights issue maybe something other ...

Comment: Are you trying to rewrite incoming URLs to the public folder? Does this mean all your other folders are accessible?